# Cakephp validation rule fires on update, even with on=>'create' specified

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I need a Cakephp 2.2 expert to help me here.
I want to make an update, with the following '$this->data':

```
array(
    'Button' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'on' => '0'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'on' => '0'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'on' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'on' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

The validation rules in the Button model are:

```
    public $validate = array(
        'id'=>array(
            'notEmpty'      => array(
                'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                'required'  => true,
                'message'   => 'Module id can not be empty',
                'on'        => 'update'
            ),      
            'naturalNumber' => array(
                'rule'      => 'naturalNumber' ,
                'message'   => 'Module id is not integer',
                'on'        => 'update'
            )
        ),      
        'name'=>array(
            'notEmpty'      => array(
                'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                'required'  => true,
                'message'   => 'Module name can not be empty',
                'on'        => 'create'                 
            ),      
            'alphaNumericWithSpaces'    => array(
                'rule'      => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i') ,
                'message'   => 'Module category is not alphanumeric'
            )
        ),
        'type'=>array(
            'notEmpty'      => array(
                'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                'required'  => true,
                'message'   => 'Module category can not be empty',
                'on'        => 'create'
            ),
            'naturalNumber' => array(
                'rule'      => 'naturalNumber',
                'message'   => 'Module category is not integer'
            )
        ),
        'on'=>array(
            'boolean'       => array(
                'rule'      => 'boolean',
                'message'   => 'Module ON value is not boolean'
            )
        ));
```

and then, in the controller, I have the following code:

```
if(!empty($this->data)) {
  if($this->Button->saveAll($this->data)) {
    debug ('Saved!');
  } 
  else {
    debug($this->Button->validationErrors);
  }
}
```

The problem is that 'saveAll()' is not making the update, and fires the following validation errors, even if I've used on => 'create' on these fields to fire only on creating the record:

```
array(
    'name' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Module name can not be empty'
    ),
    'type' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Module category can not be empty'
    )
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just so that the mechanics of saveAll don't get in the way, try using save() and a single record. With CakePHP 2.2.4, CakeValidationSet::validate() should definitely check 'on' (via $rule->skip()) before looking at 'required'.  The error suggests it is trying to do a create, instead of an update.

To save many Button records, you may want to try this $data structure instead.  And perhaps use saveMany() as well

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(   
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'on' => '0'
        )
    )
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'on' => '0'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'on' => '1'
         )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'on' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```